# How do I have the :default Rake task depend on a task with arguments?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have been playing around with Rake and Albacore, to see if I can replace our existing MSBuild script that deploys software with something that isn't XML.  I have a task that will change the debug value inside a `web.config` to `false`. The task takes the directory of the `web.config` as an argument, but I can't quite figure out the syntax needed to supply this argument in the default task.

```
require 'albacore'
require 'nokogiri'

deployment_path = 'c:/test-mars-deploy'

task :default => [ :build, :publish, :update_web_config['c:/test-mars-deploy'] ]

task :update_web_config, :deploy_path do |t, args|  
  deployment_path = #{args[:deploy_path]}
  web_config_path = File.join deployment_path, 'Web.config'

  File.open(web_config_path, 'r+') do |f|
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
    puts 'finding attribute'
    attribute = doc.xpath('/configuration/system.web/compilation')
    attribute.attr('debug', 'false')
    puts attribute.to_xml
  end

  File.delete(web_config_path)

  File.new(web_config_path, 'w') do |f|
    f.write(doc.to_s)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have to use the old style parameter passing, eg:

```
nicholas@hal:/tmp$ cat Rakefile
task :default => :all

deploy_path = ENV['deploy_path'] || "c:/some_path"

task :all do |t, args|
    puts deploy_path.inspect
end
```

And invoke with:

```
nicholas@hal:/tmp$ rake
(in /tmp)
"c:/some_path"
```

Or, to override the path:

```
nicholas@hal:/tmp$ rake deploy_path=c:/other_path
(in /tmp)
"c:/other_path"
```

Comment: I managed to refactor my code so it is run through a batch file using this method.

Comment: @Dan: can you comment on why you need a batch file?

Comment: The snippet I posted doesn't really need one, but in my actual code I have tasks that build a couple of different projects inside the one file.  I could probably separate them out into separate files, but I haven't got that far in my ruby learning.

Answer (score 2):

The task dependency notation doesn't support passing arguments. It only takes names or symbols referring to task names.

```
task :default => [ :build, :publish, :update_web_config['c:/test-mars-deploy'] ]
```

You'd need to do something like this.

```
task :default => [ :build, :publish ] do
    Rake::Task[:update_web_config].invoke 'c:/test-mars-deploy'
end
```

Remember, though, `invoke` will only work once per task, even with different arguments. It's the real dependency chain invoke. But, it will call all dependent tasks. You can use `execute` if you need multiple executions, but that won't call dependent tasks.

```
Rake::Task[:update_web_config].invoke 'c:/test-mars-deploy'
Rake::Task[:update_web_config].execute 'c:/test-mars-deploy2'
Rake::Task[:update_web_config].execute 'c:/test-mars-deploy3'
```

In general, I don't recommend either of these approaches. Calling `invoke` or `execute` seems to me to indicate a poorly structured task. You simply don't have this problem if you don't prematurely parameterize.

```
web_config = 'c:/test-mars-deploy/Web.config'

task :update_web_config do
  File.open(web_config, 'r+') do |file|
    # ...
  end
end
```

If you *must* parameterize, provide an array or `FileList` and generate the tasks per item.

```
web_configs = FileList['c:/test-*/Web.config']

web_configs.each do |config|
  task config do
    File.open(config, 'r+') do |file|
      # ...
    end
  end
end

task :update_all_web_configs => web_configs
```

Better yet, I [published](https://rubygems.org/gems/fileupdatetasks) a [config update task](https://github.com/AnthonyMastrean/FileUpdateTasks) that does all of this mess for you! Provide a `FileList` to update and a hash of xpath queries => replacements.

```
appconfig :update_web_configs do |x|
  x.files = FileList['c:/test-*/Web.config']
  x.replacements = {
    "/configuration/system.web/compilation/@debug" => 'False' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

basically, you name your args as extra symbols after the name of the task. an args param will get passed into the block that responds to the name of your args, and you can invoke the task passing the args in square brackets (`[]`)

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02@rails3 matt@Zion:~/setup$ cat lib/tasks/blah.rake 
task :blah, :n do |t, args|
  puts args.n
end
ree-1.8.7-2010.02@rails3 matt@Zion:~/setup$ rake blah[20]
(in /home/matt/setup)
20
```

Comment: Yes, it runs correctly from the command-line using the above, but what I am looking for is how to pass the argument using the default task so that I can just type 'rake'.

Answer (score 0):

The task dependency notation does in fact support passing arguments. For example, say "version" is your argument:

```
task :default, [:version] => [:build]

task :build, :version do |t,args|
  version = args[:version]
  puts version ? "version is #{version}" : "no version passed"
end
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
$ rake
no version passed
```

or

```
$ rake default[3.2.1]
version is 3.2.1
```

or

```
$ rake build[3.2.1]
version is 3.2.1
```

However, I have not found a way to avoid specifying the task name (default or build) while passing in arguments. Would love to hear if anyone knows of a way.