# Pass arguments to Rake default task without specifying task name

Tags: ruby, rake

Using the task dependency notation, you can pass in arguments to the default task. For example, say "version" is your argument:

```
task :default, [:version] => [:build]

task :build, :version do |t,args|
  version = args[:version]
  puts version ? "version is #{version}" : "no version passed"
end
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
$ rake
no version passed
```

or

```
$ rake default[3.2.1]
version is 3.2.1
```

or

```
$ rake build[3.2.1]
version is 3.2.1
```

However, I have not found a way to avoid specifying the task name (default or build) while passing in arguments.

Does anyone know of a way to use this notation and not have to specify the task name? (i.e. take advantage of the "default" syntax as well?)

I know of the ENV[] approach of receving parameters, as described here: 
[How do I have the :default Rake task depend on a task with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467347/how-do-i-have-the-default-rake-task-depend-on-a-task-with-arguments/19481524#19481524)

I'm looking for a way to use the built in notation (as shown above) but avoid having to specify the task name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the rake source code, you can see that it is not possible ([GitHub](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/application.rb#L688-L698)):

```
# Collect the list of tasks on the command line.  If no tasks are
# given, return a list containing only the default task.
# Environmental assignments are processed at this time as well.
def collect_tasks
  @top_level_tasks = []
  ARGV.each do |arg|
    if arg =~ /^(\w+)=(.*)$/m
      ENV[$1] = $2
    else
      @top_level_tasks << arg unless arg =~ /^-/
    end
  end
  @top_level_tasks.push(default_task_name) if @top_level_tasks.empty?
end
```

In this method, tasks to be run are collected from provided arguments. Everything that starts with `-` is ignored, everything in form `foo=bar` is used to set the environment and everything else is treated as task name.

If you specify task with arguments (`foo[bar]`) the arguments are parsed in [`parse_task_string`](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/application.rb#L152-L161).

If you do not specify the task, `default` is used without any arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to follow the code as we'll but got lost. Do you think a patch to allow this makes sense? I guess the syntax would look a bit wierd